# Is there an end of support plan for Classic Content | Microsites?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, microsites, support

Next year support for classic content will begin to end in Email Studio. So far, the official documentation says this is limited to Classic emails.

However I still find the documentation on Microsites and Classic Content ambiguous. Can anybody tell me what “until you move to CloudPages” means in the screenshot below or seen [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsites.htm&type=5)?  Can we expect Classic Content Microsite feature to be deprecated? I have an account where Microsite and CloudPages are both enabled and functioning.

[image]

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsites.htm&type=5
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_update_to_classic_content_end_of_support_plan.htm&type=5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that means "until [you're ready to] move to CloudPages" (i.e., CloudPages aren't missing any features that I need). From the [Content Builder FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_classic_landing_pages_and_microsites.htm&type=5):

> What if I Want to Create Content for Classic Landing Pages and Microsites?
>
> Where possible, use CloudPages.
>
> Support for classic Landing Pages and Microsites goes beyond the end-of-support and end-of-life dates unless the functionality is added to CloudPages.

I would take that to mean Classic Landing Pages and Microsites aren't being deprecated until feature parity is reached. I've worked with some of SFMC's largest customers who have literally hundreds if not thousands of active landing pages in classic content, so I doubt they'll have the rug pulled out from under them overnight.

That being said, unless you still require [features available only in classic landing pages or microsites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_web_tools_comparison.htm&type=5), I'd move over to CloudPages today.

Comment: Its an interesting one for sure. Thank you for your answer Mark. We have Microsites and CloudPages available. However, only microsites has been provisioned with custom domain branding while CloudPages currently is not. That is going to require extra investment. So we have a decision to make about the path we want to take. Keep using Classic or invest in CloudPages and start using that. 
I wish the documentation was more explicit about this, so we dont have to translate and interpret it!

Comment: You just need to buy Private Domain for Cloud Pages, and possibly an additional SSL certificate